# Converse of theorem on differentiating term by term

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

A well-known theorem states that if $\sum_n \frac{d}{dx} a_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent then the series $\sum_n a_n $ can be differentiated term by term, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}\sum_n a_n(x) = \sum_n \frac{d}{dx} a_n(x)$.

Is the converse of this theorem true? That is, if a series of functions is not uniformly convergent does that imply that you cannot differentiate term by term? My intuition says no but I am also wondering if the failure of uniform convergence implies anything of interest with regard to derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ does *not* converge uniformly on $[0,1)$ to $\frac1{1-x}$. Nevertheless, it is true that$$\bigl(\forall x\in[0,1)\bigr):\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)'.$$

Comment: Well, I have used that derivative trick hundreds of times, but I had never realized that  the convergence is not uniform... I have no idea about why it works.

Comment: @ajotatxe It works because the convergence *is* uniform on every interval $[0,a]$ ($a\in[0,1)$).